# Specify install directories, with PEP 517 installer

Tags: python, software-packaging

How can I specify, to a PEP 517 conformant installer, the directories where libraries and scripts should be installed?

### Deprecated Setuptools installer does it right

Using `python3 -m setup install --install-lib=/usr/share/foo/ --install-scripts=/usr/share/bar/`, I can specify the installation location for Python libraries and executable programs.

```
$ python3 -m setup install --help
[…]
Options for 'install' command:
[…]
  --install-lib                        installation directory for all module
                                       distributions (overrides --install-
                                       purelib and --install-platlib)
[…]
  --install-scripts                    installation directory for Python
                                       scripts
[…]
```

This is good, when installing a self-contained application; the program files should end up in a location appropriate to the operating system, and the libraries should be installed in an application-private directory because they're not for general import by other Python programs.

The Setuptools project has [deprecated the `setup install` feature](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/history.html#setup-install-deprecation-note), so we need to find a replacement for this.

### PEP-517 tools to do this?

The current simple ['build' tool](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (“A simple, correct Python build frontend”) apparently does not have corresponding options to specify the installation directories that way.

### Need a direct replacement for `--install-lib` and `--install-scripts`

I want to migrate away from deprecated `setup install`, to a PEP-517 build system.

But I need (for some applications) to be able to specify the install location of library modules, and of console scripts. Just like with the old `--install-lib` and `--install-scripts` options.

How do I instruct 'build' to do this? Or, what other PEP-517 conformant installation tool lets me do this?

Comment: This is not the job of the build tool, but the job of the installer (e.g. pip).

Comment: You probably want the `--prefix` and/or `--target` options to `pip install`.

Comment: If the problem is simply "install the code as an application rather than a reusable package", that is what `pipx` is for.

Comment: Hmm, if you really want to put files to `/usr/share/...` then you should use `.rpm` packaging or similar. Python packaging does not really have the necessary features for an application deployment.